# What's going on with this old question getting completely changed years after the last activity?

Tags: discussion

For some reason, [this old question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/131242/what-does-the-term-vf-on-chinese-power-tool-battery-packs-48vf-or-88vf-mean) has been completely changed in the last few weeks to something that makes both of the existing answers entirely wrong. Why? One of the edits says "to clarify the intent of the original poster", but how can one know the intent of the original poster?

I'm specifically wondering about revision 5 here:
[image]

The question was completely changed from "What is meant by Vf?" to something about Chinese power tools that have "Vf" marked on them, without any indication that the original asker was talking about power tools. This revision was made on January 26 of 2021, more than six years after the question was posted and subsequently closed on September 29 of 2014.

Comment: Honestly, that question is poor enough I don't know why it just isn't deleted.

Comment: @DKNguyen It's not exactly a fantastic question, no.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the problems started by the 3rd edit which is where the meaning significantly changed. The game of 'telephone' continued until the present day. It seems to me that the best course of action would be to roll it back so I did that.

Another way to request a roll back would be to flag it for mod attention.

Comment: I almost rolled it back myself, I just wasn't sure if that would have been the correct thing to do.

Comment: Yeah, it is the correct thing. And the rollback also goes to the edits que, so it will get another set of eyes on it. Be sure to explain why you did the rollback.